# How to create UI in spring-boot like spring-boot-admin and springfox-swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, spring-boot-admin

I am using spring-boot-2.2.1 and Java-8. Just I have gone through this page https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin and I am keen to create UI like this in my application. we have some functional flows in the JSON file in our application classPath and I would like to visualize those files in UI using diagrams. I see spring-boot-admin and spring-fox swagger and I would like to create or follow exactly the same principle to create UI for the flows in my application. Are there any guidelines or principles we have to follow to create UI?

Any hint or pointers would be really helpful. I don't know how to start or what framework they are using to create UI.

Comment: why not just use their program?

Comment: and if you look into the source code you can see that they are using VueJS to produce the GUI https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-server-ui/src/main/frontend